# How to assign a product to be taxable in multiple states?

Tags: magento, states

My concern is I am developing a site in `magento` where client needs an ability to specify taxes per state at category or product level.

To be more specific, there are some products in the store that are taxable in more than one US states like electronic items are taxable in NY, NJ and CA.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento allows for a lot a flexibility in setting tax rates. Go to `Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rates` and specify as many rates as you'd like there. Rates can apply to whole countries, whole states, and specific zip codes.

Answer (score 0):

In your use case for say - stereo receivers ( assuming there's a unique tax rate per state for this category of electronics ).  You could do the following:

- Create a product tax class:  specialelectronics
- Create a tax rate:  usa-ny-specialelectronics ; usa ; ny ; * ; rate = 10%
- Create a tax rate:  usa-nj-specialelectronics ; usa ; nj ; * ; rate = 20%
- Create a tax rate:  usa-ca-specialelectronics ; usa ; ca ; * ; rate = 50%
- Create a tax rule:  specialelectronics; retail customer ; specialelectronics ; usa-ny-specialelectronics, usa-nj-specialelectronics, usa-ca-specialelectronics

Note you can only assign a product to one product tax class.